# How do I add string to an array x2 and the get it back?

Tags: vb.net

Essentially what I am trying to do is write a program where you input the person's name and their date of birth, store them to an array (note sure if I have to do two separate arrays) and then by entering their name into another text box and clicking another button I can get the date of birth back.

I know I have to include an **`if`**-loop, I know how to declare an array.

I am guessing that I maybe need to use a select case.

Here is the code:

```
Public Class Form1
Dim Name(5) As String
Dim DOB(5) As String
Dim i As Integer
Private Sub btnNameEnter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNameEnter.Click

    Name(i) = txtInputName.Text
    DOB(i) = txtInputDOB.Text

    If i = 6 Then
        MsgBox("You cannot enter any more names.")
    End If

    For i = 1 To 5
        Name(i) = i
        txtInputName.Clear()
        txtInputDOB.Clear()
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub btnFindDOB_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFindDOB.Click
    Select Case Name(i)
        Case Is Name(1)
            MsgBox("Date of birth: " & DOB(1))
        Case is Name(2)
            MsgBox("Date of birth: " & DOB(2))
        Case is Name(3)
            MsgBox("Date of birth: " & DOB(3))
        Case is Name(4)
            MsgBox("Date of birth: " & DOB(4))
        Case is Name(5)
            MsgBox("Date of birth: " & DOB(5))

    End Select
End Sub
End Class
```

I would show a picture of the program but visual basic keeps deleting it for some reason and doesn't let me re add the buttons.

Here is an image of the error list: 
http://gyazo.com/2489a307f4a8e2d9ce65aa2ad79b04f1 [image: ScreenShot-error-list] )

---

Public Class Form1
    Dim DOB(5) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Private Sub btnEnter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
        Dim Name(5) As String

```
    Dim Counter As Integer
    txtNameInp.Text = Name(i)
    txtDOBInput.Text = DOB(i)

    Counter = 0

    For i = 1 To 5
        If Counter = 6 Then
            MsgBox("You can only enter 5 names and DOBs")
        End If
        Name(i) = txtNameInp.Text
        DOB(i) = txtDOBInput.Text
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub btnFindDOB_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFindDOB.Click
    Select Case Name(i)
        Case Name(1)
            MsgBox(DOB(1))
        Case Name(2)
            MsgBox(DOB(2))
        Case Name(3)
            MsgBox(DOB(3))
        Case Name(4)
            MsgBox(DOB(4))
        Case Name(5)
            MsgBox(DOB(5))
    End Select
End Sub
```

End Class

Here's an error: http://gyazo.com/487290c3e523003fe58f82a15fdf6faa - this one occurs when I try and enter the second number

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to be to precise using a picture of the errors instead of comments in the code indicating the location and text of the error, but from what I can see:

- Forms already have a `Name` property and you are trying to redefine it via your array.  use something like `myNames` instead.
- You have a module level variable named `i` and a local one as well.  Change the global one to something useful like `curPosition`.  This will track with element you are currently storing to.
- If you want to stop adding to the array at 6 you need to do so in code.  Add `Exit Sub` after the MsgBox; you want to do this *before* you store anything to the arrays, not after.  Maybe add a message saying - 'now I will tell you the DOB for a name`.
- If you want to be clever (doubtful) have both a 'Guess Name' and `Guess DOB` button on the form and report the Name for a given DOB.  Its basically the same code.
- the button enter code will run every time they click so you do not need a loop.  This is plain nonsense by the way: `Name(i) = i` you are overwriting everything with whatever `i` happens to be.  Just add to `myNames` and `myDOB` using `curPosition` as the index and then increment it:

  myNames(curPosition) = txtInputName.Text
- The relational error is from this: `Case Is Name(1)`

The error is *telling* you that it expects a relational operator, which `Is` is not (`Is` is used with Objects, which a string is not).  The code is also a bit wonky here because you are not controlling the value if `i`.  To compare `txtInputName`:

```
Select Case txtInputName.Text   
    Case = Name(1)       ' ie does txtInputName match the value in Name(1)?
      ...
```

- Rather than a case statement, you could use a For Loop here for less code.

---

Lets learn about classes.  Rather than arrays which will dissociate related pieces of info from each other a class will keep the data together.

```
Public Class Person

    Public property Name As String
    Public Property DOB As DateTime       ' I refuse to store a Date as string

    Public Sub New(sName as String, dt as DateTime)
       Name = sName
       DOB = dt
    End Sub
End Class
```

Next, a nifty list to hold some person objects.  A list is like an array but smarter:

```
Private pList As New List(Of Person)
```

Add a person:

```
' ToDo: check that the date is valid using TryParse instead
' this exercise is left to the student
Dim p As New Person(txtInputName.Text, Datetime.Parse(txtInputDOB.Text))
plist.Add(p)
```

Find a person:

```
' case insensitive search
Dim search As String = txtNameToFind.Text.ToLowerInvariant

For Each p as Person In pList
    If P.Name.TolowerInvariant = search Then
        txtDOB.Text = p.DOB.ToString
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: http://gyazo.com/a5a41bc860d54c56dcd84de56027f6f1 I'm confused what to do, the people in my class did with just an if statement and select case.

Comment: an if statement and select case would work, just not the way you were using them.  as homework, a Class and List are probably not a good idea if you havent learned about them yet. start by working thru the changes mentioned in the first part (Name, i, Is) etc.  and keep in mind programming is an exercise in precision; warnings mean things

Comment: I have no idea how to write it though, I don't get how they did barely any code and got it to work, I can't declare Name because of some 1D array bs.

Comment: well whining about it will sure help.  I told you what that problem may be: a form already has a Name property, so use `myNames` for your array. I cant be certain because we dont know which line of code relates to that error - you need to be clearer in describing problems.  click on the error and it will take you to the line and you can mark it in your post so we know whats what

Comment: Ok, I rewrote the code, still doesn't work. I will include some images of the errors as well. (I'll post it as an answer)

Comment: see also [Arrays In Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Name, DOB As List(Of String) 'Lists are better in this situation.

    Private Sub btnNameEnter_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNameEnter.Click
        'You don't need to specify the index in lists.
        Name.Add(txtInputName.Text)
        DOB.Add(txtInputDOB.Text)

        txtInputName.Clear()
        txtInputDOB.Clear()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnFindDOB_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFindDOB.Click
        'You get the index of the name you are searching for and get DOB for this index.
        MsgBox("Date of birth: " & DOB.Item(Name.IndexOf(txtInputName.Text)))
    End Sub
End Class
```